# Are there any markup that allows me to set its DataContext but doesn't do anything as graphic?

Tags: xaml, markup-extensions

I'm working on a project where things aren't build "very well". Because I want create something like a "partial model" for a part of the window where I will put my controls, I would like to know if there is a markup that will allow me to specify its DataContext but doesn't change the window graphic in any way (adding buttons and things like that).

If not, how can I create one by myself (I think by intheriting MarkupExtension), and more important: can be done?

Thanks for any answer

**EDIT 1:**

An example of my idea is this one:

```
<SomeControl>
    <TextBlock />
    <ThisMarkupDoNothing DataContext="{Binding my:Model}">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyModelProperty}" />
    </ThisMarkupDoNothing>
</SomeControl>
```

Maybe this can help understand what I mean.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand your question.  Are you asking if you can specify a DataContext on a panel (Layout Control)?

Comment: I'm posting an example in the edit 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`ContentControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx) for that:

```
<SomeControl>
    <TextBlock />
    <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding my:Model}">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyModelProperty}" />
    </ContentControl>
</SomeControl>
```

Other options include `UserControl` and `Border` without actually setting the border properties.

Comment: I think contentcontrol fit well!